# 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized. when I use FileZilla Client to connect the Server

Tags: sftp

I installed the FileZilla Server on my Windows Server. and when I use the FileZilla Client to connect it there gets bellow error:

```
https://filezilla-project.org/
Connecting to server...
Connected, waiting for authentication
Logged on
(000018)2018/10/24 10:56:18 - (not logged in) (50.184.220.141)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000018)2018/10/24 10:56:18 - (not logged in) (50.184.220.141)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.43 beta
(000018)2018/10/24 10:56:18 - (not logged in) (50.184.220.141)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
(000018)2018/10/24 10:56:18 - (not logged in) (50.184.220.141)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000018)2018/10/24 10:56:18 - (not logged in) (50.184.220.141)> SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.32.0
(000018)2018/10/24 10:56:18 - (not logged in) (50.184.220.141)> 500 Syntax error, command unrecognized.
```

The FileZilla Server listen on the port 21.

In my Client I use `sftp://102.33.56.81`, port `21` to connect the Server, but get failed, the Server log is upper.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the FileZilla Server default use FTP protocol, it use the port `21`.

when you connect it can not use sftp protocol, just use ftp to connect.

```
ftp://102.33.56.81
```